SQL SSIS Failure Creating File
I have an SSIS package that loads data from an Excel file into SQL. The package runs fine locally. Had to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (32-bit) to get the SSIS package to read the Excel file.  When I deployed and ran the package on the SQL SSIS server I get the following error message.

Package: Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has
occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine" Hresult 0x80004005
Description: "Failure creating file.".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do you have that driver installed on the server?  Does the ID that is running the job have permissions to the folder?  Can the server running the job even have access to where you are trying to create the file at?

@Brad the service account for the server was granted permissions to the sharefile drive.  Looks like the server has the 64-bit driver installed.

"Had to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (32-bit) to get the SSIS package to read the Excel file." - You had to? Did you consider using any of the other versions/editions of the ACE OLE-DB driver (such as 2016/2019 and x64?), or the non-Access "Microsoft Excel Driver" for ODBC?

@Dai I did install 2016 (64-bit) at first, but still unable to read the Excel file.  Can't remember the exact error I was getting, but I think it was telling me to install 32-bit.  I was unable to install the 2016 32-bit version.  It kept saying to uninstall the 64-bit version even though I did.  So I gave up and found a download version of 2010.  I didn't try any other versions/editions besides that.
